# How do I include the API key in apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I keep trying to include the API Key in the fetch sequence, but I keep getting 401.
Using CURL works.

This is what they provide as reference for Javascript:

```
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Authorization', "Bearer YOUR_API_KEY")

fetch("https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/eth-mainnet/address/0xA27503E089EF0e37D6eaF28aA444c46eB9FD9E40 /portfolio_v2/", {method: 'GET', headers: headers})
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

and this is what I try to do in Apps Script:

```
function getHistory() {
  wallet = "0x"
  apiKey = "xxxxx"
  link = "https://api.covalenthq.com/v1/eth-mainnet/address/"+wallet+"/portfolio_v2/&api_key="+apiKey

  options = {
     "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization" : apiKey,
     }
   };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link, options);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Any pointers ?